# Is there a commonly used way of identifying "institutional" domain names?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, domain-registrar

Not sure which SE site is exactly the best for this so apologies if this is out of place here.

I have a database that I add emails to, and I want to join users that I suspect to be in the same organization under the same account. An easy way to do this is to look at the email domain and put people who have the same domain in the same account. This is fine, but if an org uses subdomains then this sometimes will put people who are actually from the same company or institution, in different accounts. For example, `dept1.myorg.com` emails will be separated from `dept2.myorg.com` emails.

So I could say, alright then let's only look at the second level domain. This will correctly join the `myorg.com` emails, but of course now I'll have the worse problem of joining every single `co.uk`, `com.ar`, `.com.au` etc., under the same account.

How do people typically differentiate these domain names that really act more like a TLD? Is there simply a list? Or perhaps something in the whois can help me?

Comment: Related on Stack Overflow: [Get domain name without subdomains using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32263695/2234742). The gist of it is that you'll need to use the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/).

Comment: I knew there had to be a list! Thank you so much, this solves my question, do you want to add your comment as an answer?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I noticed that for example `wordpress.com` is not included in the list, do you know a reason for that?